# Stable PgAdmin alternative for querying Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres SQL with PgAdmin for quite a while now but it almost always crashes when our internal firewall kills idle TCP connections after a timeout. This bug seem to exist for years from version to version in PgAdmin.

I have not found any good alternative to query Postgres. I do not use a lot of fancy features, only SQL, schema browsing, export of data to csv occasionally and work on Windows.

Any stable free for commertial use alternatives UIs for Postgres with good track record?

Posted same at SO but closed there as off topic, trying my luck here at softwarerecs

Answer (score 1):

Google for dbeaver. Universal tool for a lot of databases.